# How do I keep an icon/sprite from moving in fluid design

Tags: css, sprite, fluid

I want to keep my icons from moving in my fluid design. The header responds to width changes and it takes up about 500 px of height and its supposed to fit into certain areas of the background (In my case an illustrated scroll", but when I resize the window and the header contracts the sprites move, eventually getting out of the scroll placement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the article for you:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/13/coding-qa-with-chris-coyier-responsive-sprites-responsive-font-sizing-media-query-efficiency-more/

It addresses this question:

```
"Is there a preferred/suggested way of handling responsive sprites at all for multiple resolutions and image scaling? Is this even possible?"
```